# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'DepartmentId'

Tags: asp.net

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key DepartmentId

I have already tried to show the departmentlist using the model

TestController.cs

```
public ActionResult Drop()
        {
            SampleEntities db3 = new SampleEntities();
            List<tblDepartment> department = db3.tblDepartments.ToList();
            ViewBag.DepartmentList = department;
            return View();


        }
```

Drop.cshtml

```
@model  WebApplication7.Models.EmployeeViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Drop";
}

<h2>Drop</h2>

<div class="container-fluid" style="width:40%">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.DepartmentId,ViewBag.DepartmentList as 
SelectList,"--Select--",new {@class="form-control" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your model create a new class. Try to use ViewModel

```
public class tblDepartmentVW
{
    public int tblDepartmentid{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tblDepartment> tblDepartments{ get; set; }
    //other data
}
```

In your Controller

```
    public ActionResult Drop()
    {
        SampleEntities db3 = new SampleEntities();
        tblDepartmentVW deptmodel= new tblDepartmentVW  {
        tblDepartments =db3.tblDepartments.ToList(),
        //fill your properties from database
        }
        return View(deptmodel);
    }
```

[Check this link for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)